# google maps v3: check if geojson feature exists on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am looking to find a way of checking if a geometry feature (from big geojson object) is already added to the map (it has already contains other geojson object with lots of features) in google maps v3 (javascript). I've searched everywhere and the only solutions I have found does not work just coming up with the following error:

> InvalidValueError: not a Geometry or LatLng or LatLngLiteral object

I also searched by the error, but I didn't find the answer that works for me, because two test geojson object are almost the same and it is ok when I try to add the to the map without any check.

I created a pen here http://codepen.io/hackzilla/pen/qqYjzB

Here is the code:

```
// add first pool of data
GoogleMap.data.addGeoJson(jsonGeoData_1);

// add second pool of data
jsonGeoData_2.features.map(function(feature, index) {
  // if the feature is on the map
  if(!GoogleMap.data.contains(feature)){
    GoogleMap.data.add(feature);
  }
  else console.log('feature' + index + 'already exist');
})
```